# Company withholding part of my final check

Tags: united-states, salaried-pay

I recently quit my job not seeing eye to eye with my manager.  I was paid $300 salary plus an hourly wage twice a month.   When I went back today to get my final paycheck they only paid the hourly rate.

To get the extra $300 each check I had to work 40 hours a week, which I did for the time period that ended.  This is in Oklahoma.

Can the employer change my final check like that and withhold the $300?

Comment: Was the 300 a bonus?  Or was that your salary?  If salary, could you clarify the problem?

Comment: It was salary I started getting paid this back last summer. I would 375 every pay check as long as I worked 40 hours every week. We get paid every 5th and 20th and I went today to grab my check but it was regular 2.15 pay. I quit this Sunday due to not seeing eye to eye with my manager anymore I was just wondering if it was legal for them to change my pay like that.

Comment: This is in southwest Oklahoma

Comment: Do you need to give a formal notice, before you quit?

Comment: Yes I worked the 40 hours. And no my manager put me on the schedule on my birthday when I told them 2 weeks and the week leading up to it that I needed that day off and when I came in that day we got into it he started talking mess so i walked out.

Comment: @user32191 Please [edit] your comment answers into your original question. While you're doing that make sure your question gives the facts in exact chronological order. And stop using 'and' sentences - they make it hard to understand. **And add a question**. It's now only a complaint.

Answer (score 4):

Start by letting them know that the check is short and ask them for the balance.

If they tell you no.  Then *politely* let them know that your next step is to file a complaint with the Oklahoma Department of labor.  Then ask, again, if they are going to cut a check for the balance.

If they still say no, then go ahead and file: http://www.ok.gov/odol/documents/WageClaimForm.pdf

Note that page 2 of this form states that you need to have asked the employer for the missing wages.

Comment: Should I do this in person or over the phone?

Comment: I'd do it in person at an appropriate time.  In other words I would **not** try to discuss it in front of customers during a busy lunch time.  Above all, be respectful and courteous even if you don't feel they deserve it.

Comment: @user32191 oooooooooh! if they have an email address (and they probably do, it is 2015 you know?) *after* your conversation with them, *if* they don't agree to paying the balance *send them an email, something like "as i discussed with you earlier today, i am requesting whatever-amount and as you are disputing this amount i will be filing a labor complaint form*. That way you have a verifiable record of having told them, should you need it.

Comment: You may want to ask for the missing wages in person, but ABSOLUTELY make sure you also ask for them either by email or in writing (and preferably by registered letter) so that you later have proof that you have asked for them. If possible get a response in writing.